# Linq to Entities using joins and generic Lists

Tags: linq, list, generics

I'm using Linq and just started working with it.
My gridview was populating when I was using a single table, but now I am trying to join a Client First Name from the Client Info table.

Error is Event_Setup does not contain a definition for ClientFirstName. So it is checking Event_Setup table instead of Client_Info.

```
public List<EventData> GetDetails()
    {
        using (EMSEntities db = new EMSEntities())
        {
            var context = from events in db.Event_Setup
                          join clients in db.Client_Info on events.ClientId equals clients.ClientId 
                        select events;

            List<EventData> newEvent = new List<EventData>();

            foreach (var e in context)
            {
                EventData test = new EventData();

                test.Event_Title = e.EventTitle;

//Error on e.ClientFirstName, Event Setup does not contain Definition
 (located in Client_Info table not Event Setup)
                test.Name = e.ClientFirstName;
                test.Start_Date = e.EventDateFrom;
                test.End_Date = e.EventDateFrom;



               newEvent.Add(test);                
            }
            return newEvent;
         }         
    }
```

DAL

```
public class EventData
{        
        public string Event_Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Start_Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? End_Date { get; set; }            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not doing anything with the joined `clients` data. You can see it is just selecting `events`:

```
var context = from events in db.Event_Setup
              join clients in db.Client_Info on events.ClientId equals clients.ClientId 
              select events;
```

Once you get out of that LINQ statement, `clients` is gone. It doesn't merge any data for you. You need to do a projection, like this:

```
var context = from events in db.Event_Setup
              join clients in db.Client_Info on events.ClientId equals clients.ClientId 
              select new EventData
              {
                  Event_Title = events.EventTitle,
                  Name = clients.ClientFirstName,
                  Start_Date = events.EventDateFrom,
                  End_Date = events.EventDateFrom
              };
```

Comment: thank you for that, now I just need to figure out how to get only date from those fields

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that Cory, here's what the list would like for anyone who views this questions

```
foreach (var e in context)
            {
                EventData test = new EventData();

                test.Event_Title = e.Event_Title;
                test.Name = e.Name;
                test.Start_Date = e.Start_Date;
                test.End_Date = e.End_Date;           

                newEvent.Add(test);                
            }
            return newEvent;
```

Comment: You can use initialization syntax to make this even simpler: `newEvent.Add(new EventData{Event_Title = e.Event_title, Name = e.Name, Start_Date = e.Start_Date, End_Date = e.End_Date})`

Comment: In fact, it looks like you're just copying from one enumeration of EventData to another, so you might as well just say `List<EventData> newEvent = context.ToList();`